# How to create a Layout of Rows in html Consisting of DIV elements

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnFTM.jpg)

Something Like this,
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex style here to create that layout. So the HTML would be as follows.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Thanks